# Suppose that $G$ is finite and that $|A|$ is coprime to $|K|=|G:A|$. If there exists a subgroup $K$ of order $k$, prove that $G=AK$.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is finite and that $|A|$ is coprime to $|K|=|G:A|$. if there exists a subgroup $K$ of order $k$, prove that $G=AK$. Stating any theorem used in the proof.

I am not sure but I think it has something to do with;

Theorem (Cauchy)
Let $p$ be a prime dividing the order of the abelian group $G$. Then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

Corollary
Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and let $k$ divide $n$. Then $G$ has a subgroup of order $k$.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$|AK|=\frac{|A||K|}{|A \cap K|}$$

Comment: in a previous part of a question i have just proved this so i thought this might be a starting point but i am not sure how.

Comment: Well, $|A|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime, so what do you know about $A \cap K$? Secondly $|G|=$|A|.|G:A|=|A|.|K|$, so ...